# -[EngineerModel _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Getting this error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EngineerModel _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I've read [How to resolve 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861626/how-to-resolve-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) and others.

Using Xcode 4.5.1 with arc (my first time with arc)

Here's my code, which is based on an earlier non-arc project which works great

database.m

```
// Models for data
#import "EngineerModel.h"

- (NSArray *)returnEngineers
{
    NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM engineers";

    stmt = nil;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            char *engineerIDChr =         (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
            char *engineerNameChr =         (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
            char *engineerSigFileChr =         (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);
            char *engineerPhoneChr =   (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3);
            char *engineerEmailChr =          (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4);
            char *engineerRegNoChr =            (char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5);

            NSString *engineerID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:engineerIDChr];
            NSString *engineerName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:engineerNameChr];
            NSString *engineerSigFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:engineerSigFileChr];
            NSString *engineerPhone = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:engineerPhoneChr];
            NSString *engineerEmail = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:engineerEmailChr];
            NSString *engineerRegNo = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:engineerRegNoChr];

            EngineerModel *info = [[EngineerModel alloc] initWithUniqueId:engineerID
                                                               engineerName:engineerName
                                                                     engineerSigFile:engineerSigFile
                                                         engineerPhone:engineerPhone
                                                                engineerEmail:engineerEmail
                                                                  engineerRegNo:engineerRegNo];

            [retval addObject:info];            
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Database has two entries

And the model

```
//  EngineerModel.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EngineerModel : NSObject
{
    NSString *_engineerID;
    NSString *_engineerName;
    NSString *_engineerSigFile;
    NSString *_engineerPhone;
    NSString *_engineerEmail;
    NSString *_engineerRegNo;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *engineerID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *engineerName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *engineerSigFile;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *engineerPhone;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *engineerEmail;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *engineerRegNo;



- (id)initWithUniqueId:(NSString *)AengineerID
          engineerName:(NSString *)AengineerName
       engineerSigFile:(NSString *)AengineerSigFile
         engineerPhone:(NSString *)AengineerPhone
         engineerEmail:(NSString *)AengineerEmail
         engineerRegNo:(NSString *)AengineerRegNo;

- (id) init;

@end


//  EngineerModel.m
#import "EngineerModel.h"

@interface EngineerModel ()

@end

@implementation EngineerModel

@synthesize engineerID, engineerName, engineerSigFile, engineerPhone, engineerEmail, engineerRegNo;

- (id)initWithUniqueId:(NSString *)AengineerID
          engineerName:(NSString *)AengineerName
       engineerSigFile:(NSString *)AengineerSigFile
         engineerPhone:(NSString *)AengineerPhone
         engineerEmail:(NSString *)AengineerEmail
         engineerRegNo:(NSString *)AengineerRegNo
{

    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.engineerID = AengineerID;
        self.engineerName = AengineerName;
        self.engineerSigFile = AengineerSigFile;
        self.engineerPhone = AengineerPhone;
        self.engineerEmail = AengineerEmail;
        self.engineerRegNo = AengineerRegNo;

     }
    return self;
}

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Lastly

I've added -ObjC and -all_load to other linker flags

Added @synthesize (I didn't think I had to for arc?)

If I simplify it down to

```
- (id)initWithId:(NSString *)AengineerID
{
    NSLog(@"AengineerID %@",AengineerID);

    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.engineerID = AengineerID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It traces AengineerID then crashes

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_isNaturallyRTL` is a private method on `NSString`.  So somehow you've got an `EngineerModel` instance where some other code is expecting an `NSString`.

What do you do with that array of `EngineerModel` objects you return from the `returnEngineers` method?

---

And just as a recommendation... using the sqlite3 C API yourself like that is a lesson in frustration.  I highly recommend using something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) instead.

Comment: AH. Yes. I'm populating a UIPickerView. instead of arrEngineers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Numpty", etc..., nil] I did arrEngineers = [[escgasDatabase database] returnEngineers]; I'm guessing I need to extract the string from [[escgasDatabase database] returnEngineers]. I assuming the crash was happening in the model as it was working up to wiring that in

Comment: Thanks, the crash come after the model. All working, now to remove all that extra junk I put in getting it to work!