# How to track down error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am getting the following error:

```
-[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x56bb95c
```

Is it possible to track down what's the variable responsible of this error? The stack call is not helping me in this scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861626/how-to-resolve-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `BOOL` type while you are considering it as `NSString` and trying to compare with some other string by `isEqualToString:`

```
 [__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]
  ....^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is what i thought but how can i spot in my code wich variable trigger this error?

Comment: If you are not sure, you called explicitly isEqualToString or you have a BOOL. Then you can use BreakPoint from init/viewDidLoad and go on to check each one. step over/step into etc